I have a question about 404 not found a page
I have problems with tags. They are disable in Yoast SEO but wordpress generate pages that give me 404 no found.
They look something like this

tag/costum/cine-ne-recomanda/

Where cine-ne-recomanda is a page in my website.
How can i find this pages?
Thanks in advance.
